# Can someone look over my error and guide me towards a fix

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Below is my error basicaly for a game im making this is my crafting script its trowing me this error can someone help

**Assets/scrpts/Crafting.js(91,81): BCE0024: The type 'UnityEngine.GUIContent' does not have a visible constructor that matches the argument list '(UnityEngine.GameObject, String)'.**

```
#pragma strict

var MenuSkin : GUISkin;

//References
var player : GameObject;
var mainCamera : GameObject;
var arms : GameObject;

//Icons
var campfireIcon : Texture;
var tentIcon : Texture;
var woodwallicon : Texture;
var spareIcon2 : Texture;
var spareIcon3 : Texture;
var spareIcon4 : Texture;

//Player prefabs
var campFire : GameObject;
var tent : GameObject;
var woodwall : GameObject;
var spare2 : GameObject;
var spare3 : GameObject;
var spare4 : GameObject;


private var showGUI : boolean = false;

private var invScript : Inventory;

function Start()
{
    invScript = GetComponent(Inventory);
}

function Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("c"))
    {
        showGUI = !showGUI;
    }

    if(showGUI == true)
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0;
        player.GetComponent(FPSInputController).enabled = false;
        player.GetComponent(MouseLook).enabled = false;
        mainCamera.GetComponent(MouseLook).enabled = false;
        arms.GetComponent(PlayerControl).enabled = false;
    }

    if(showGUI == false)
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        player.GetComponent(FPSInputController).enabled = true;
        player.GetComponent(MouseLook).enabled = true;
        mainCamera.GetComponent(MouseLook).enabled = true;
        arms.GetComponent(PlayerControl).enabled = true;
    }
}

function OnGUI()
{
    if(showGUI == true)
    {
        GUI.skin = MenuSkin;
            GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 150, Screen.height / 2 - 150, 300, 300));
                GUI.Box(Rect(0, 0, 300, 300), "Crafting System");

                if(GUI.Button(Rect(10, 50, 50, 50), GUIContent (campfireIcon, "Build a campfire")))
                {
                    if(invScript.wood >= 6)
                    {
                        campFire.SetActive(true);
                        invScript.wood -= 6;
                        invScript.stone -= 3;
                    }
                }

                if(GUI.Button(Rect(10, 120, 50, 50), GUIContent (tentIcon, "Build a tent")))
                {
                    if(invScript.wood >= 6 && invScript.stone >= 3)
                    {
                        tent.SetActive(true);
                        invScript.wood -= 6;
                        invScript.stone -= 3;
                    }
                }


                if(GUI.Button(Rect(10, 190, 50, 50), GUIContent (woodwall, "Build a wooden wall")))
                {
                    if(invScript.wood >= 3 && invScript.iron >= 1)
                    {
                        woodwall.SetActive(true);;
                        invScript.wood -= 3;
                        invScript.iron -= 1;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Check the available constructors for GUIContent, make sure your constructors match one of them. That is, when you construct a CUIContent object, make sure its arguments match the arguments needed for one of the supplied constructors.

Comment: That's not Java, not by any stretch.

Comment: Yes, please change the tag to javascript instead of java

Comment: nope, it's not even javascript

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because you have passed the arguments swapped, `GUIContent` constructor looks like,

```
GUIContent(text: string, image: Texture)
```

So you may need to change the input to suit the constructor that is available.

```
GUIContent ("Build a campfire", campfireIcon)
```

Further in a future need check for the [Unity Scripting API](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference)